# Is there a function that lets my control the number of var args?

Tags: julia

I have the following code:

```
circ(x) = x./sqrt(sum(x .* x))

x -> cat(circ(x), circ(x); dims = 1)
```

but I want to be able to create a function where I input a number and it concatenates that number of circ(x)s.

so for example:

```
function Ncircs(n)
  #some way to make cat() have as its parameter circ n number of times
end
```

and I could call `Ncircs(2)` and get
`x -> cat(circ(x), circ(x); dims = 1)`
or `Ncircs(3)` and get
`x -> cat(circ(x), circ(x), circ(x); dims = 1)`
or `Ncircs(4)` and get
`x -> cat(circ(x), circ(x), circ(x), circ(x); dims = 1)`

etc.

Is there a way of doing this? Do I have to use a macro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write:

```
Ncircs(n) = x -> cat(Iterators.repeated(circ(x), n)...; dims = 1)
```

and if you know you will be doing `dims=1` always then replating `cat` with `vcat` and `reduce`

```
Ncircs(n) = x -> reduce(vcat, Iterators.repeated(circ(x), n))
```

will be more efficient for large `n`.

As a side note: using the other option (`vcat`) will produce a type stable result while the first option is not type stable.

**EDIT**

#### Why reducing over an empty collection is not allowed?

In general the reason is that then you are not able to tell what should be the result of the reduction. If you want to allow an empty collection you should add `init` keyword argument. Here is an example:

```
julia> reduce(vcat, [])
ERROR: ArgumentError: reducing over an empty collection is not allowed

julia> reduce(vcat, [], init = [1])
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1

julia> reduce(vcat, [[2,3], [4,5]], init = [1])
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
```

#### What does it mean that the result is type-stable

It means that Julia is able to tell what is the type of the return value of a function at compilation time (before you execute the code). Type stable code usually runs faster (this is a broad topic though - I recommend you to read the Julia manual to understand it in detail). You can check if the function is type stable using `@code_warntype` and `Test.@inferred`.

Here let me give you an explanation in your specific case (I truncated some of the output to shorten the answer).

```
julia> x = [1,2,3]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> y = [4,5,6]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 4
 5
 6

julia> @code_warntype vcat(x,y)
Body::Array{Int64,1}
...

julia> @code_warntype cat(x,y, dims=1)
Body::Any
...

julia> using Test

julia> @inferred vcat(x,y)
6-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6

julia> @inferred cat(x,y, dims=1)
ERROR: return type Array{Int64,1} does not match inferred return type Any
```

`Any` above means that the compiler does not know what will be the type of the answer. The reason is in this case that this type depends on `dims` parameter. If it is `1` it will be a vector, if it is `2` it will be a matrix.

#### How do I know that it will be more efficient for large `n`

You can run `@which` macro:

```
julia> @which reduce(vcat, [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
reduce(::typeof(vcat), A::AbstractArray{#s72,1} where #s72<:(Union{AbstractArray{T,2}, AbstractArray{T,1}} where T)) in Base at abstractarray.jl:1321
```

And you see that there is a specialized `reduce` method for `vcat`.

Now if you run:

```
@edit reduce(vcat, [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
```

An editor will open and you see that it calls an internal function `_typed_vcat` that is optimized for `vcat`-ing a lot of arrays. This optimization was introduced because using a splatting like this `vcat([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]...)` is equivalent in the result, but you have to do splatting (the `...`) which in itself has some cost that can be avoided using the `reduce` version.

In order to make sure that what I say is true you can do the following benchmark:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> y = [[i] for i in 1:10000];

julia> @benchmark vcat($y...)
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  156.45 KiB
  allocs estimate:  3
  --------------
  minimum time:     67.200 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      77.800 μs (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        102.804 μs (8.50% GC)
  maximum time:     35.179 ms (99.47% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     1

julia> @benchmark reduce(vcat, $y)
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  78.20 KiB
  allocs estimate:  2
  --------------
  minimum time:     67.700 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      69.700 μs (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        82.442 μs (6.39% GC)
  maximum time:     32.719 ms (99.58% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     1

julia> @benchmark cat($y..., dims=1)
ERROR: StackOverflowError:
```

And you see that `reduce` version is slightly faster than splatting version of `vcat`, while `cat` simply fails for very large `n` (for smaller `n` it would work but simply be slower).

Comment: Thank you! This is a terrific response! I'm wondering if you wouldn't mind answering a few questions so that I may learn: how do you know that it will be more efficient to use your suggestion for large n? Also, what does it mean for a result to be type stable?

Comment: Additionally, I want to optionally set n to zero but reducing over an empty collection is not allowed. How would I address this? Also I have looked back over the context and realized that I will never actually need a very large n at all if that helps.

Comment: I will add additional comment in the answer.